# WP8 BackgroundTransferService thread exit message are displaying a long time even after completed downloads

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, background-transfer

I am using `BackgroundTransferService` in my application for downloading zip file form the server.

And it works successfully for me. But it seems it gets some thread exit messages continuously even after downloading file.

The messages like as follows

```
The thread 0x3d68 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4080 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4300 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4084 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x431c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x44fc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x41c0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4144 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x17cc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3b14 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
.....
..
```

Why this messages are showing long time even after the download completed?
Is that because of some bg service not dispose properly?

Comment: The code 0 is it ended normally without errors its normal to see this message when you use multi threading (including Asinc Await and Task.Run).

Comment: But when i try to load a web browser with local content [java script is in it] before the debug message stops , the script is functioning with delay and no issues if i load after  messages get stopped.

Comment: without further code analyses its difficult to say with certainty but that usually happens when you don't have any reference for a resource and after a while the Garbage collector collects it and its behaviour disappear.If a thread stops and no reference to the result is saved it will eventually be collected again it would need further analyses.

Comment: @Pedro.The.Kid Thanks for the answer. I just called GC.Collect method after downloading and the Thread exit messages stopped displaying.